# Change font of text in anyfield using iOS Keyboard Extension

Tags: iphone, ios8, ios8-extension, ios-keyboard-extension

I am working on an iOS Keyboard Extension. I need to use a custom font in my keyboard extension. This part is completed.
Now the problem is that, if i type in safari or any other app using my keyboard extension, the character typed their should also be in my custom font style.

Same like this application on app store works

https://itunes.apple.com/US/app/id923893166?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

I spent almost 1 day to find a way to do this, but i didn't find any result.
If anybody here can help me, Please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the font in *any* textfield on iOS.

The developers have instead found some sets of unicode characters that cover the alphabet and represented them to users as a font.

If you copy paste the phrase "ᏴᎬᎦᏆ" from one of the glowing reviews allegedly written by a user of this keyboard (incidentally, iOS 3rd-party keyboards cannot currently type reviews in the App Store) and paste it into UnicodeChecker, you will find that it is actually the unicode characters U+13F4, U+13AC, U+13A6, and U+13C6.

The actual codes for the word "Best" are U+0042, U+0045, U+0053, and U+0054.

If you want to make your own Unicode keyboard, a list of "fonts" can be found at http://unicode-table.com/.